# Issue with value types and init’s

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

I’m following an [old tutorial](https://youtu.be/-8qnERZ6u8Q) on setting up a data structure to view RGBA values in an image.  For the most part of gotten past all of the out of data stuff, but I’ve run into an issue that seems super simple, I’m just relatively new to swift, so it’s proving to be a bit more difficult.

```
import UIKit

public struct RGBAPixel {
    public init(rawVal : UInt32) {
        raw = rawVal
    }
    public var raw: UInt32
    public var red: UInt8 {
        get { return UInt8(raw & 0xFF) }
        set { raw = UInt32(newValue) | (raw & 0xFFFFFF00) }
    }
    public var green: UInt8 {
        get { return UInt8( (raw & 0xFF00) >> 8) }
        set { raw = (UInt32(newValue) << 8) | (raw & 0xFFFF00FF) }
    }
    public var blue: UInt8 {
        get { return UInt8( (raw & 0xFF0000) >> 16) }
        set { raw = (UInt32(newValue) << 16) | (raw & 0xFF00FFFF) }
    }
    public var alpha: UInt8 {
        get { return UInt8( (raw & 0xFF000000) >> 24) }
        set { raw = (UInt32(newValue) << 24) | (raw & 0x00FFFFFF) }
    }
}

let image = UIImage(named: "crossSection.jpg")

let height = Int((image?.size.height)!)
let width = Int((image?.size.width)!)
let bitsPerComponent = Int(8)
let bytesPerRow = 4 * width
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let rawData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.allocate(capacity: width * height)
let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
let CGPointZero = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: (image?.size)!)

let imageContext = CGContext(data: rawData, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)

imageContext?.draw(image!.cgImage!, in:rect)

let pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt32>(start: rawData, count: width * height)

///*
for var y in 0 ..< height {
    for var x in 0 ..< width {
        var p = pixels[x+y*width] = RGBAPixel(rawVal: 0)
        p.red = 255
        pixels[x+y*width] = p


    }
}
//*/

let outContext = CGContext(data: pixels.baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)

let outImage = UIImage(cgImage: outContext!.makeImage()!)
```

There are two issue points.  First is the issue near the bottom when put into swift it gives the error “Cannot assign value of type ‘RGBAPixel’ to type ‘UInt32’”.  I followed the [video](https://youtu.be/-8qnERZ6u8Q) pretty well and looked for any errors I can’t seem to find.  It seems like this issue isn’t something that would be from an update so I’m very confused.
I researched structs and inits and it seems to make sense the way the code is written.  The init is allowing the data type UInt32 to be passed in through RGBAPixel.  Again, very new so correct me **where** I’m wrong. Thanks

Comment: I think you want `p.raw` not `p`

Comment: @Paulw11 are you talking about the line ```pixels[x+y*width] = p``` That didn’t have an effect on the problem.  The problem line is ```var p = pixels[x+y*width] = RGBAPixel(rawVal: 0)``` This is supposed to turn all the pixels black.

Comment: Then you need `.raw` at the end of that too. `pixels` is declared as holding `UInt32` so you can’t assign `RGBAPixel` to it, as the compiler is telling you.

Comment: In fact that line doesn’t make much sense. The code after is treating `p` like it is a. `RGBAPixel` but it is going to be an `UInt32`

Comment: Awesome! Adding the .raw to the end of the line made it work! Any idea on you can access say the red value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `<UInt32>` instead of `<RGBAPixel>`

```
let rawData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.allocate(capacity: width * height)
//Should be:
let rawData = UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBAPixel>.allocate(capacity: width * height)
```

Same with:

```
let pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt32>(start: rawData, count: width * height)
// Should be:
let pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<RGBAPixel>(start: rawData, count: width * height)
```

Try this (I added a few blank lines for readability) - uses black for colour:

```
import UIKit

struct RGBAPixel {
    var raw: UInt32

    public init(rawVal : UInt32) {
        raw = rawVal
    }

    public var red: UInt8 {
        get { return UInt8(raw & 0xFF) }
        set { raw = UInt32(newValue) | (raw & 0xFFFFFF00) }
    }

    public var green: UInt8 {
        get { return UInt8( (raw & 0xFF00) >> 8) }
        set { raw = (UInt32(newValue) << 8) | (raw & 0xFFFF00FF) }
    }

    public var blue: UInt8 {
        get { return UInt8( (raw & 0xFF0000) >> 16) }
        set { raw = (UInt32(newValue) << 16) | (raw & 0xFF00FFFF) }
    }

    public var alpha: UInt8 {
        get { return UInt8( (raw & 0xFF000000) >> 24) }
        set { raw = (UInt32(newValue) << 24) | (raw & 0x00FFFFFF) }
    }
}

let image = UIImage(named: "crossSection.jpg")

let height = Int((image?.size.height)!)
let width = Int((image?.size.width)!)

let bitsPerComponent = Int(8)
let bytesPerRow = 4 * width

let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

let rawData = UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBAPixel>.allocate(capacity: width * height)

let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue

let CGPointZero = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)

let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: (image?.size)!)

let imageContext = CGContext(data: rawData, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)

imageContext?.draw(image!.cgImage!, in:rect)

let pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<RGBAPixel>(start: rawData, count: width * height)

///*
for var y in 0 ..< height {
    for var x in 0 ..< width {
        pixels[x+y*width] = RGBAPixel(rawVal: 0xFF000000)
    }
}
//*/

let outContext = CGContext(data: pixels.baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)

let outImage = UIImage(cgImage: outContext!.makeImage()!)
```

To use the colours:

```
for var y in 0 ..< height {
    for var x in 0 ..< width {
        var p = RGBAPixel(rawVal: 0xFF000000)
        p.red = 128
        pixels[x+y*width] = p
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s right! Ugh thank you so much! I was so sure I had everything the same as the video.  Much appreciated.